# How do I set "global" headers in fetch whatwg

Tags: fetch

In jquery you can do this:

```
$.ajaxPrefilter(function(options) {
    options.headers = {  
        "X-API-KEY": "APIKEY"
    };
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That does not exist. You can suggest it at https://github.com/whatwg/fetch/issues/new but I think we'll keep the API simple for now and let libraries build functionality like this on top.

Comment: yup, I reached the same conclusion. It's trivial to implement in user land and it would probably cause problems when third party scripts start using fetch.